# why the sendto function needs the third parameter, in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, sendto

I was new to socket program. 
When learning the `sendto` function, as the prototype:

```
ssize_t sendto(int socket, const void *message, size_t length,
                int flags, const struct sockaddr *dest_addr,
                socklen_t dest_len);
```

I get to know that the "message" has contain the target IP, and the `dest_addr` argument also specifies the target IP address.
Is there other usage of the `dest_addr` argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message does **not** contain the destination address, only the payload bytes.

Unless you are using raw sockets... And you should not do that if you are new to socket programming.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for the partial state of the question. I am  using the raw sockets to send ICMP message. It's obvious that you are very familiar of socket.  Could you tell me whether the "dest_addr" is just  void in row scket?

Comment: @Akr: Raw sockets, eh? Well, from `man 7 raw`: "Sending on raw sockets should take the IP protocol from sin_port; this ability was lost in Linux 2.2.  The workaround is to use IP_HDRINCL". So my guess is that the `dest_*` arguments are mostly ignored, and you would better with just `send` instead of `sendto`.

Answer (score 10):

I think you are confusing "message" and "dest_addr".

Let's look at the prototype for sendto in expanded form:

```
ssize_t sendto   (int sockfd,
                 const void *buf,
                 size_t length,
                 int flags,
                 const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, 
                 socklen_t addrlen);
```

sockfd - this is the socket you created with a call to socket()

buf - this is a pointer to an ARRAY OF BYTES (i.e. they could have made buf of type char* ). That is, this is the data that you want to send across the wire encapsulated in a UDP packet.

length - this is how many bytes are in that array.  If you didn't pass "length", it wouldn't know if "buf" was 1 byte or 10000 bytes.

flags - Typically 0.  This is advanced stuff

dest_addr - this is a pointer to the destination address.  Typically you initialize a sockaddr_in instance and cast its pointer value to a sockaddr* type.

addrlen - the size of the dest_addr.  typically, sizeof(sockaddr_in).  Address length is variable because dest_addr could pointer to an IPV4 address (sockaddr_in type) or an IPV6 address (sockaddr_in6 type), or some other type.

Example of sending a packet from local port 9999 to remote host "1.2.3.4" on its port 8888.  Error checking of return codes left out for brevity.

```
int s;
sockaddr_in addrDest;
sockaddr_in addrLocal;
char* msg = "Hello World";

// create the socket
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); // UDP socket


addrLocal.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrLocal.sin_port = htons(9999);
addrLocal.sin_addr = INADDR_ANY; // zero-init sin_addr to tell it to use all available adapters on the local host

// associate this socket with local UDP port 9999
result = bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addrLocal, 0);

// send "Hello world" from local port 9999 to the host at 1.2.3.4 on its port 8888
addrDest.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrDest.sin_port = htons(8888);
addrDest.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("1.2.3.4");

// strlen(msg)+1 for terminating null char
result = sendto(s, msg, strlen(msg)+1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addrDest, sizeof(addrDest));
```

Comment: Great response. Respect!

Answer (score 3):

No, Message Contains what you will send, here is an example:

```
int spatula_count = 3490;
char *secret_message = "The Cheese is in The Toaster";

int stream_socket, dgram_socket;
struct sockaddr_in dest;
int temp;

// first with TCP stream sockets:

// assume sockets are made and connected
//stream_socket = socket(...
//connect(stream_socket, ...

// convert to network byte order
temp = htonl(spatula_count);
// send data normally:
send(stream_socket, &temp, sizeof temp, 0);

// send secret message out of band:
send(stream_socket, secret_message, strlen(secret_message)+1, MSG_OOB);

// now with UDP datagram sockets:
//getaddrinfo(...
//dest = ...  // assume "dest" holds the address of the destination
//dgram_socket = socket(...

// send secret message normally:
sendto(dgram_socket, secret_message, strlen(secret_message)+1, 0, 
       (struct sockaddr*)&dest, sizeof dest);
```